# How to upgrade package

Tags: ros, update, laser-scan-matcher, package, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I was wondering whether one could more or less easily **upgrade a package (indigo -> kinetic or even up to lunar)** by installing it with the source code taken on git in a catkin_ws ?

I'm for example thinking about:

- [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node)
- [laser_scan_matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher)

I couldn't find a tutorial on that, and especially need to update laser_scan_matcher from source by adding odometry to the node with  [already developped code](http://answers.ros.org/question/12489/obtaining-nav_msgsodometry-from-a-laser_scan-eg-with-laser_scan_matcher/) . One of my problems for doing that being that  [laser_scan_matcher git repository](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools) is associated with Indigo and not kinetic. Furthermore, the package install with apt doesn't offer (or at least I don't know how) the possibility to add the [.h](https://pastebin.com/hY5pFWsY) and  [.cpp](https://pastebin.com/ebtxMGAD)  files that permit the usage of odometry with that particular node.

Thanks to anyone considering my question ! Really trying to understand ROS but it is sometimes frustrating ^^

Blupon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265915/how-to-upgrade-package/) by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2017-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, you can totally build those packages from source. Odds are good that the packages will work just fine in the new distribution, but you might have to make a few tweaks to get them to work. Check out the [Kinetic Migration Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration) and the [Lunar Migration Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Migration).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-11**:
thanks ! I forgot those pages, going to read them right away. If it's not a problem, I'll let this thread open a little longer just in case I encounter what I see as a newbie dead end

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-19**:
@EdVanator It appears migrating the packages I considered would be too painful - they depend on other packages which would request migration and so on... Anyway thanks for your answer !

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-07-21**:
I just remembered that you can check [this page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/blocked_releases_lunar.html?q=label%3D%22UNRELEASED%22&s=6&r=1) to see whether a package has been released and if there are any unreleased dependencies.